# How to send email using Run As Account in runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I want to send an email using the "Run As account" in the Azure Automation account - Runbook. I am using the $smptpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'

---

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
while(!($connectionResult) -and ($logonAttempt -le 10))
{
   $LogonAttempt++
Logging in to Azure...
  $connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount `
                       -ServicePrincipal `
                       -Tenant $connection.TenantID `
                       -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID `
                       -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}

 Send-MailMessage -To $StrMessageTo -Subject $StrMessageSubject -Body $StrMessageBody -UseSsl - 
 Port 587 -SmtpServer $StrSmtpServer -From "usertest.com" -BodyAsHtml
```

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: So, what happens then? Do you get an error?

Comment: Have you tried changing `$StrSmtpServer` to `$smptpServer`?

Comment: @alexzelaya:- Yes that one has corrected it but some service account issue was there. So after change the new service account, It got fixed.

Comment: So does that mean the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [alexzelaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15387068/alexzelaya) and [Sudhir Goswami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6653070/sudhir-goswami). Posting your discussions as Answer to help other community members.

changing `$StrSmtpServer` to `$smptpServer` and replacing the Service account fixed the issue